# Ruby—sort_by multiple levels of sorting

Tags: ruby, sorting

I have two strings, `s1` and `s2`

I want a list of characters (from both strings), sorted:

- **first** by how many times the char appears in one of the strings (the greater value)

e.g. `"hello"`, and `"goodbye"` would be `"lloogbehyd"`

- **second** by whether the max chars appear in s1 or s2

e.g. `"hello"`, and `"goodbye"` would be `"lloohegdby"`

- **third** alphabetically

e.g. `"hello"`, and `"goodbye"` would be `"lloohebdgy"`

Currently I have this code:

```
letters = (s1+s2).chars.uniq.sort_by{ |s| [s1.count(s), s2.count(s)].max }.reverse
```

This sorts by the first condition, how do I add the other levels?

Comment: Hint: Arrays are sorted by their first element, and in the case of a tie, their second, and so on.

Comment: You need to be more precise in describing "second". There are three possibilities: greater number in `s1`, equal number in `s1` and `s2` (In my answer and greater number in `s2`. How are these to be ordered in the sort? (In my answer I assumed the order in which I listed the three possibilities applies.) Please clarify by editing as not everyone may notice an explanatory comment.

Comment: @jtbandes, I don't think so. Yes, the question is partly about multilevel sorting but it's also about the construction of the particular arrays that are to be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Using [String#count](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-count) is relatively inefficient, as the entire string is traversed for each unique letter. It would be more efficient, at the expense of more lines of code, to create a *counting hash*, which can be done as follows (see [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-c-new)).

```
s1 = "hello"
s2 = "goodbye"

h1 = s1.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 }
  #=> {"h"=>1, "e"=>1, "l"=>2, "o"=>1} 
h2 = s2.each_char.with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |c,h| h[c] += 1 }
  #=> {"g"=>1, "o"=>2, "d"=>1, "b"=>1, "y"=>1, "e"=>1}
hmx = (h1.keys | h2.keys).each_with_object({}) do |c,h| h[c] =
  case h1[c] <=> h2[c]
  when 1 then [-h1[c], -1]
  when 0 then [-h1[c], 0]
  else [-h2[c], 1]
  end
end
  #=> {"h"=>[-1, -1], "e"=>[-1, 0], "l"=>[-2, -1], "o"=>[-2, 1],
  #    "g"=>[-1, 1], "d"=>[-1, 1], "b"=>[-1, 1], "y"=>[-1, 1]}
```

We can now sort using 
[Enumerable#sort_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by)

```
(s1+s2).each_char.sort_by { |c| [*hmx[c], c] }.join
  #=> "lloooheebdgy"
```

See [Array#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) (third paragraph) for an explanation of how arrays are sorted.

I've made the assumption that if two characters tie for the most occurrences in one of the two strings, each character is assigned a score of `-1`, `0` or `1`. The character with the lowest score (if they don't have the same score) precedes the other character in the sort. A character `c` is assigned a score of `-1` if the string `s1` contains more `c`'s than does string `s1`; a score of `0` if both strings contain the same number of `c`'s; and a score of `1` if `s2` contains more `c`'s than does `s1`.

Answer (score 0):

What I eventually did:

```
(s1+s2).chars.sort_by{ |s| 
  [-([s1.count(s), s2.count(s)].max), 
    s1.count(s) > s2.count(s) ? -1 : 1, 
    s]
}
#=> "lloohebdgy"
```

The generalised answer is that giving an `Array` to the `sort_by` block allows you to specify levels of sorting.

Comment: You forgot `.join` after the closing brace. That returns `"llooohbdeegy"`.